# Change row count doesn't work in materialize css text area

Tags: html, css, materialize

In [materialize css text area](http://materializecss.com/forms.html), is it possible to initialize the text area with a specific row count using "rows='20'" ? How can we increase the default row count ?

code which doesn't work:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
   <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" rows="20" ></textarea>
   <label for="textarea1">Text</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default stylesheet is setting a height so you'll have to override that.

```
textarea.materialize-textarea{height: 6rem;}
```

Comment: Not work for me. Maybe we used different material css. But I have solve this case with simple !important.
`textarea {
   height: 90vh !important;
}`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of that you can add style attribute like this

```
<textarea class="materialize-textarea" style="height: 200px;"></textarea>
```

And materialize won't override it

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.

```
$('#textarea1').val('New Text');

M.textareaAutoResize($('#textarea1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, materializecss changes the basic concepts of DOM, HTML, etc.

```
textarea {
     height: your height;
     width: your width:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this

```
<textarea class="materialize-textarea" style="height: 200px;"></textarea>
```

But my textarea was hide and I shown it with jQuery but don't work.

`$('#textarea').show();`

So i do it and works correctly.

```
$('#textarea').show(function(){
        $(this).css("height","80px");
    });
```